# jquery client side validation not working after deploying in server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, client-side-validation, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I am using asp.net mvc 5 (C#) for my application. Client side validation works fine in local, but in server its not working.

Below is from the BundleConfig.cs

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"
    ));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"
    ));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"
    ));
```

Below is the from _Layout.cshtml(added at the bottom):

```
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
  @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
 </body>
</html>
```

Below is my signin page:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SignIn", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "signInForm" }))
{
    <div class="titleBg"><h2>Sign In</h2></div>
    <table>
        <tr><td class="spacer50 taC" colspan="2">@Html.ValidationSummary(true)</td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:40%;" class="taR pRight10">
                <label for="EmailAddress">Email</label>
            </td>
            <td class="fieldName">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmailAddress, new { maxlength = "100", @class = "field mLeft10 email", style = "", @tabindex = "1" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="taR">
                <label for=" password">Password</label>
        </td>
            <td class="fieldName">
                @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { maxlength = "12", @class = "field mLeft10 pass", style = "", @tabindex = "2" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
            </td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
           <td colspan="2" class="spacer10"></td>
       </tr>
        <tr><td></td>
            <td class="taL">
                <input id="btnSignIn" type="submit" value="Sign In" class="mLeft10" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

Below is how the EmailAddress field gets rendered in Local:

```
<input type="text" value="" tabindex="1" style="" name="EmailAddress" maxlength="100" id="EmailAddress" data-val-required="Email Address is required" data-val-email="Email Address is invalid" data-val="true" class="field mLeft10 email">
```

Below is how the EmailAddress field gets rendered in Server:

```
<input type="text" value="" tabindex="1" style="" name="EmailAddress" maxlength="100" id="EmailAddress" class="field mLeft10 email">
```

Config in Local and Server:

```
<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

The above implementation works perfect in the local, but we move this to the server, the client side validation is not working. data-val attributes is missing when we run the website in server.

Can someone please suggest what am i missing here?

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: No Errors are there in the browser. I have checked in the firebug console too

Answer (score 3):

I was running into the same problem. It ended up that my Web.Config transform was set to "replace" the default web.config appSetting section.

It worked once I made sure these settings were in the config:

`<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>`

Comment: Shut.. mine stopped working in prod as well due to same problem...
Forgot completely about transform....

Comment: Me too. Seems like default settings for this should be ON, not off.